# run time error 2465

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I am getting error in MS access 2003, Run Time Error 2465: Microsoft can't find the field '|' referred to in your expression.

```
Count = DCount("*", "PREPAYMENT_PRICING_CHANGE", ([INSERT_DATE] - Int([INSERT_DATE])) = ([Now()] - Int([Now()])))
db.Execute "INSERT INTO tbl_audit ([FilePath],[FileName],[action],[trans_date],[button],[number_of_records])" _
       & " values ( '" & strFName & "', '" & File & "'  , ""'Import_of_NTS_rate_PCD_file'""  ,Now() ,""'Import NTS rates from file'"",'" & Count & "');"
```

Comment: What are the values of the variables when that happens?

Comment: Have you escaped your values variables? Try Replace(strFName,"'","''")

Answer (score 1):

I think that you forgot the `"` in the `DCount` condition:

```
Count = DCount("*", "PREPAYMENT_PRICING_CHANGE", "([INSERT_DATE] - Int([INSERT_DATE])) = ([Now()] - Int([Now()]))")
```

Also try to escape your variables:

```
db.Execute "INSERT INTO tbl_audit ([FilePath],[FileName],[action],[trans_date],[button],[number_of_records])" _
       & " values ( '" & Replace(strFName,"'","''") & "', '" & Replace(File,"'","''") & "'  , ""'Import_of_NTS_rate_PCD_file'""  ,Now() ,""'Import NTS rates from file'"",'" & Count & "');"
```